# PHP script to execute cronjob: update bp members last activity status to current time based on role

Tags: php, cron, buddypress, buddyboss

I'm using this php script that is supposed to update bp members last activity status to current time but I'm getting a HTTP 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
// Include WordPress bootstrap
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('path_to_wordpress_installation/wp-blog-header.php');

// Function to randomly update last_activity for 150 BuddyPress members with a specific role
function update_random_members_last_activity($role) {
    $users = get_users(array(
        'role' => $role,
        'number' => 150, // Limit the number of users to 150
        'orderby' => 'rand', // Order randomly
    ));

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        bp_update_user_last_activity($user->ID);
        // Optionally, perform other tasks with each user here
        echo "Updated last activity for user: " . $user->display_name . "<br>";
    }
}

// Call the function with the desired role
$role = 'your_role'; // Replace 'your_role' with the actual role
update_random_members_last_activity($role);

?>
```

I was expecting 150 members' last activity status to be randomly updated based on their role.

Comment: Do you really mean `path_to_wordpress_installation` ?

Comment: Go check what the error log has to say; that is _always_ the first thing to do, when you get a 500 Internal Server Error.